# recursive macro arityexception

Tags: macros, clojure, arity

I am trying to write a macro similar (I think) in function to the threading macro, however this would allow me to specify a keyword where the previous form's insertion would happen.  I was planning on using clojure.walk/prewalk-replace, but I am getting a clojure.lang.ArityException. Here is the code:

```
(defmacro streamops [data form]
  (let [keewurd :...]
    (cond
      (not (seq? form)) form
      (= (count form) 0) data
      :else (streamops ~(clojure.walk/prewalk-replace
                          {keewurd data} (first form))
                       ~(rest form)))))`
```

but when I try to apply the unit test:

```
(= (macroexpand '(streamops 3 ( (+ 1 :...) (* :... 2))))
   '(* (+ 1 3) 2))
```

It produces:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (-1) passed to: walk$prewalk-replace
       Compiler.java:6473 clojure.lang.Compiler.macroexpand1
            core.clj:3633 clojure.core/macroexpand-1
            core.clj:3642 clojure.core/macroexpand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On another note, have a look at [swiss-arrows](https://github.com/rplevy/swiss-arrows#a-generalization-of-the-arrow), there is a macro that does what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misplaced syntax-quote `` ` `` in the definition of your macro, since it is placed at the end of it in the code you posted, but there's no syntax-quoting in the forms where you use unquote `~`.

The following works just fine:

```
(defmacro streamops [data form]
  (let [keewurd :...]
    (cond
      (not (seq? form)) form
      (= (count form) 0) data
      :else `(streamops ~(clojure.walk/prewalk-replace
                          {keewurd data} (first form))
                       ~(rest form)))))

(= (macroexpand '(streamops 3 ( (+ 1 :...) (* :... 2))))
   '(* (+ 1 3) 2))

;= true
```

Comment: Is the code re-evaluated for macro-expansion after the first macro expand? This seems to be returning a form containing the macro, which  then would not be evaluated, since it is returned as regular code.

Comment: Yes, the code is re-evaluated and the result from `macroexpand` returns `(* (+ 1 3) 2)`. Additionally, the use of `macroexpand-1` returns `(user/streamops (+ 1 3) ((* :... 2)))`, as expected.